# Laravel - como salvar ses houver alguma alteração no model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema que é o seguinte 
gostaria de saber se o Laravel tem algum método que verifique se alguma alteração foi realizada antes de salvar o model
Exemplo.

tabela users, se o usuário solicitou editar o nome, mas não alterou nada, e mandar salvar, é aceito de boa! porém gostaria que só salvasse se realmente houvesse uma mudança!

pela minha pesquisa existe um método **isDirty** mas não entendi o seu conceito.

> OBS: eu exemplifiquei um model simples, poderia fazer a verificação
>   manual, mas vamos pensar em um model bem maior com muitos atributos,
>   não seria viável realizar manualmente.

se alguém puder dar o caminho das pedras eu fico feliz!

Answer (score 0):

[Esse é o código do método `save()` do Laravel versão 5.3](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1448)

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();
    // If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return
    // false, indicating that the save failed. This provides a chance for any
    // listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false) {
        return false;
    }
    // If the model already exists in the database we can just update our record
    // that is already in this database using the current IDs in this "where"
    // clause to only update this model. Otherwise, we'll just insert them.
    if ($this->exists) {
        $saved = $this->isDirty() ?
                    $this->performUpdate($query) : true;
    }
    // If the model is brand new, we'll insert it into our database and set the
    // ID attribute on the model to the value of the newly inserted row's ID
    // which is typically an auto-increment value managed by the database.
    else {
        $saved = $this->performInsert($query);
    }
    if ($saved) {
        $this->finishSave($options);
    }
    return $saved;
}
```

observe o seguinte em seu próprio código já executa o método [isDirty](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/using-isdirty-to-check-eloquent-attribute-changes), ou seja, o que você quer verificar o próprio código do `Eloquent` já faz.

Isso fica muito claro quando tem a configuração para o campo `updated_at` que é a data e hora da última alteração no registro, se não for alterado esse dado continua com a data e hora sem atualizar, só havendo alteração quando houver alterações em seu(s) campo(s) e chamar o método `save()`.